# How to query from the dynamic database name inside the function

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

```
ALTER FUNCTION FnVersion
    (@DBName  NVARCHAR(255),
     @ID  INT)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE (iD INT, VersionNo INT)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)

    SET @SQL = @DBName

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT iD, VersionNo FROM' + @DBName + '.dbo.ConfigInfo WHERE IdValue = @ID'

    EXECUTE SQL 

    RETURN;
END
```

The db name will be passed as input and the query will be done on dynamic database
The above logic of exec SQL statement caused an error.

What is the way to achieve dynamic query from dynamic database?

Comment: Its not possible in a function. Only an SP.

Comment: any other way to achieve in function?

Comment: you could create a view that UNION ALLs the ConfigInfo tables from each database, and update the view whenever you add or remove a database.

Comment: You could have lots of `if` statements, one for each dbname?

Comment: i would avoid if statement as it impacts in performance , this function is called in multiple places

Comment: If it has to be a function you don't have many options... generic SQL as you are trying to attempt is never good for performance. SQL prefers to know what it is dealing with in advance for best performance.

Comment: The requirement itself is to query from multiple databases as i don't have any other option

Comment: Does the requirement specify a function? You can use a stored procedure with an output parameter and then use dynamic SQL. You'd have to try it to see if that performs better than a function with if statements - will depend a bit on how many databases you are accessing.

Comment: I need to have a function as im selecting results from function (selecting results is not allowed in stored proc)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use dynamic SQL in SQL Function. but make it part of procedure and store those data into temp table with remote procedure call. Performance will be better to use remote procedure rather than remote query.

you can use INSERT INTO with EXEC command. and manipulate temp table with your logic. it would be better approach.

Comment: In that case can I select values from stored without creating temp table?

Comment: Yes, you can use store procedure in wrapper of table. but i suggest to use temp table to avoid performance issues. and in wrapper you need to use server and database details.